# PHP Functions not returning anything

Tags: php, function

I'm getting extremely frustrated- for some reason my function isn't returning anything. With all my other functions they work fine. I pass arrays back and forth, no issue.

```
function get_location_data ($info,$wpdb)
{
    //Status Reports Not Working- but page not broken so Fix this.
    //Location Records
    //This is more complex b/c of the way that the DB is done. 
    $data_passed = explode("++", $info["location_station_ID"]);
    //var_dump ($info);
    //echo "<br>";
    //var_dump ($data_passed);
    $location_key = trim($data_passed[0]);
    $location_name = $data_passed [1];

    //var_dump ($location_key);
    //echo '<br>';

    //Query the DB and get all the location reports for the location
    $sql = "SELECT report_key, ship_deployment_line_key FROM stations_deployed_rows WHERE station_key = '" . $location_key . "'";

    $reports_in_db = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
    $qry = $wpdb->last_query;
    //var_dump ($qry);
    //var_dump ($reports_in_db);
    if (empty($reports_in_db))
    {
        echo "No Records for location " . $location_name . "\n";
        $total_report = "None";
    }
    else
    {
        $total_report = array();
        $loop_c = 0;
        foreach($reports_in_db as $key)
        {
            ++$loop_c;
            $total_report [$loop_c] = $key;                     
        }

        //var_dump ($total_report);
        $tables_to_sort = sort_rows_into_tables ($total_report,"ship_deployment_line_key", $wpdb);      
        print_report_types ($tables_to_sort);
    }

    return $total_report;
}
```

basically what I want to do - is remove the print call from this function, and instead return the array of lines to be printed.

```
$data_passed = explode("++", $_POST ["location_station_ID"]);
$tables = get_location_data ($data_passed,$wpdb);
var_dump ($tables);
```

this is where the function is being called.

However: when I var_dump `$tables` - nothing shows up. The function is in a different file from where it's being called (though this shouldn't be an issue- lots of functions in the functions file return values)

Any ideas about what's happening?

Comment: When you say " nothing shows up", what **exactly** is the output of `var_dump ($tables);`?

Comment: Enable error reporting also.

Comment: @ Nick- there is no output.

Nothing is shown.

Comment: You should increment `$loop_c` *after* you assign to the element. Or just push into the array rather than assigning to a specific index.

Comment: You push into an array with `$total_report[] = $key;`

Comment: @ Funk Forty Niner- I'm not sure how to do that- i code in Geany,, and then move the code to the website.

http://globalmaritimehistory.com/adm-8-database-project/ is the link- if you choose "Get Reports for a Location" - then look at *any* location, that'll be the page I'm working with.

Comment: But basically you're just making a copy of `$reports_in_db`, so you can do `$total_report = $reports_in_db;`

Comment: @Barmar I take your point, but that's not the issue. The array works *just* fine when I pass it to the print function inside this function.. but somehow it's not getting returned? at all?

Comment: These comments have nothing to do with the problem you're having, they're just ways to improve your code.

Comment: When you say "Nothing shows up", you don't even see something like `null`? `var_dump()` always produces output.

Comment: @Barmar- when I say nothing happens, I mean there is *nothing*- not null, not anything. I'm confused as hell b/c I've never seen that before.

Comment: I may be a complete idiot. I may be altering the wrong file. stand by to confirm idiocy.

(I work on tugboats and I've not slept for 30 hours or so.. so this is only partially okay)

Idiocy confirmed. I was working on the old page template.. which was superseded and all the code moved to another file.

I just moved it over and it works perfectly.

My apologies.

Comment: @Barmar- thank you for your suggestions for improving the code (in general). I appreciate it